# Нисходящая сортировка слиянием. Метод абстрактного обменного слияния

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка

Нужно реализовать нисходящую сортировку слиянием методом абстрактного обменного слияния. Вот функция абстрактного обменного слияния:

```
template <class Item>
void merge(Item a[], int l, int m, int r) {
    int i, j;
    static Item aux[maxN];
    for (i = m + 1; i > l; i--)
        aux[i - 1] = a[i - 1];
    for (j = m; j < r; j++)
        aux[r + m - j] = a[j + 1];
    for (int k = l; k <= r; k++)
        if (aux[j] < aux[i])
            a[k] = aux[j--];
        else
            a[k] = aux[i++];
}
```

Как сделать эту сортировку нисходящей, то есть рекурсивной?

Comment: Тут пока нет никакой сортировки, а есть лишь использующийся в ней (и не только в ней) примитив: слияние двух отсортированных массивов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я немного изменил вашу функцию. Среднее значение вычисляется внутри. Принцип работы алгоритма таков, что сначала исходный массив разбивается на два других. Каждый из них также разобьется ещё на два. Это будет продолжаться до тех пор, пока длина каждого подмассива будет равна 1.

```
template <class Item>
void merge(Item a[], int l, int r) {

    if (abs(r - l) <= 1) return; //конец рекурсивных вызовов
    int i, j;
    int m = (l + r) / 2;
    merge(a, l, m); //вызов для левой части
    merge(a, m+1, r); //вызов для правой части
    static Item aux[1000];
    for (i = m + 1; i > l; i--)
        aux[i - 1] = a[i - 1];
    for (j = m; j < r; j++)
        aux[r + m - j] = a[j + 1];
    for (int k = l; k <= r; k++)
    {
        if (aux[j] < aux[i])
            a[k] = aux[j--];
        else
            a[k] = aux[i++];
    }   
}
```

Замечание: при вызове функции необходимо указывать длину массива - 1. То есть:

```
int main()
{
    int a[N];
    merge(a, 0, N-1);
}
```

Comment: Понимаю, вопрос старый, но не могли бы вы прокомментировать, что происходит в этих циклах, насколько я понимаю, именно там массив разбивается надвое и поочередно записывается в дополнительный массив aux. Я нигде не ошибся? Подскажите, где массив снова соединяется в один?

Comment: @EDWIN, вы ведь сами писали эти циклы, я только реализовал сортировку. Но вообще принцип такой: надо разделить массив пополам, а потом слить их по определенным принципам. Но сливать в этот же (исходный) массив мы не можем, поэтому требуется дополнительный массив, в который будет происходить слияние. После того, как слияние завершилось, то нужно в исходный массив записать тот слитый массив.  В этом коде, где aux[i] = a[j] - это заполнение массива, в который сливаются две половины. А a[i] = aux[j] - это перезапись исходного массива